# iOs (Macbook Pro) voice over rotor limitation when using aria-describedby and viewing list of links in rotor. Link Purpose WCAG 2.2.4

Tags: ios, accessibility, wai-aria, voiceover, wcag2.0

I observed when running voice over on MacBook Pro that the aria-describedby value used to satisfy link purpose in context, WCAG 2.4.4, is not visible when I open the rotor and view the list of links.  I do hear the text when I focus directly on the element.  This is not the desired experience as the person using assistive technology is still left with an ambiguous purpose if multiple anchors contain the same link text.
I know I can use aria-labelledby to satisfy the requirement and add unique IDs to each CTA as well as the section that provides more details about links purpose.  This only adds more development work which ultimately will increase costs.

I am curious about voice over's apparent limitation.  Has anyone encountered this before?
Anyone have suggested solutions to so that one can use aria-describedby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about it.  VoiceOver is not alone.  NVDA and JAWS on the PC both list just the [accessible name](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#dfn-accessible-name) of the link and not the [accessible description](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#dfn-accessible-description).  That's intentional.  It's ok if the link does not have context in the links dialog if your context is provided via `aria-describedby`.

I typically provide all the context with `aria-labelledby` for exactly the reason you're asking about - so that the links dialog will show the full context.

Whether you use `aria-labelledby` or `aria-description` doesn't really cause "more work" or more cost.  If there is a cost, it's negligible.

In theory, this might be "less work" and sound like it might be the pattern you're using:

```
<h3 id="context">important heading</h3>
<a href="#" aria-describedby="context">learn more</a>
```

Here is what I usually do:

- add an ID to the heading (although you should already have an ID on the heading in order to reference it in aria-describedby)
- add an ID to the link
- add `aria-labelledby` to the link that references the two IDs

```
<h3 id="context">important heading</h3>
<a href="#" aria-labelledby="linkID context" id="linkID">learn more</a>
```

I don't see how the second example "increases costs" compared to the first one.  This will show the full context in the rotor links dialog.

If I want to get fancy or more grammatically correct, I'll have a hidden "about" text that I also use in `aria-labelledby`.  If I have several links, they can all point to the same "about" text.

```
<span class="display:none" id="abt">about</span>

<h3 id="context">important heading</h3>
<a href="#" aria-labelledby="linkID abt context" id="linkID">learn more</a>

<h3 id="context2">another important heading</h3>
<a href="#" aria-labelledby="linkID2 abt context2" id="linkID2">learn more</a>
```

Now the screen reader will say and display "learn more about important heading" and "learn more about another important heading".